# i want to use multiple files uploade using codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter-3

I want to upload multiple files where id = 1. I will use update batch so I can add 10 files in each row . for example. I have column name files now I want to store files name in array so I can store more than 10 files in one row and column with field name files .

---

1. Model :

   ```
       public function insertfile($uploadData =array(),$table,$id)
           {

        $insert = $this->db->update_batch($table,$uploadData, array('ID' => $id));


             return $insert?true:false;
       }
   ```
2. Controller :

   ```
   if ($btnupload  && !empty($_FILES['files']['name']))
   {

          $filesCount = count($_FILES['files']['name']).'</br>';
               for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++){
                   $_FILES['file']['name']     = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
                   $_FILES['file']['type']     = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
                   $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
                   $_FILES['file']['error']     = $_FILES['files']['error'][$i];
                   $_FILES['file']['size']     = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];

                   // File upload configuration
                   $uploadPath = 'uploads/';
                   $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
                   $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif|dll|pdf|docx';

                   // Load and initialize upload library
                   $this->load->library('upload',$config);
                   $this->upload->initialize($config);


      if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file'))
                   {
                           $error =  $this->upload->display_errors();
                           $this->session->set_flashdata('statusMsg',$error);
                           $data['post'] =$this->NewSystem_m->getsearchid($table,$id);
                                          }
                   else
                   {
                        $fileData = $this->upload->data();                   

                        $uploadData[$i]['files'] = $fileData['file_name'];
                         //$names= implode(',', $uploadData[$i]);
                        $insert = $this->NewSystem_m->insertfile($uploadData,$table,$id);
                         // Upload status message
                   $statusMsg = $insert?'Files uploaded successfully.':'Some problem occurred, please try again.';
                   $data['post'] =$this->NewSystem_m->getsearchid($table,$id);
                   $this->session->set_flashdata('statusMsg',$statusMsg);
                    if ($insert) {
                       $data['post'] =$this->NewSystem_m->getsearchid($table,$id);
                   }

                   var_dump($insert);
                    // $data['post'] =$this->NewSystem_m->getsearchid($table,$id);   
                   }



                   }
   ```
3. view :

   ```
       <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
              <p><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('statusMsg'); ?></p>
               <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
              <input type="submit" name="fileSubmit" value="UPLOAD"/>
               </div>
   ```

   error =
   One or more rows submitted for batch updating is missing the specified index.

Comment: can you add a ptint_r of your uploadData in the controller,
and i see you call the finction insertfile on each loop, why ?

Comment: Soufiane Lamnizeh i added loop so i can insert multiple file in one row.